# Why does PCI passthrough not give my device to the guest OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, pci, pci-passthrough, iommu

I want to try PCI passthrough. I have passed an old capture video card to a Windows XP guest.

`IOMMU` is enabled;
`vfio_pci` is loaded

I run this command:

```
virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_05_05_0

lspci -s 00:05 -v
```

It reports `vfio` is "running" the PCI device, but when I start XP with PCI devices, it gives me back this error:

```
Please ensure all devices within the iommu_group are bound to their vfio bus driver.
```

What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.
First the IOMMU group must be identified; in my case is 11(I found it using `lspci` and reading pci address,in my case it is 05:05:0)

```
find /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/ -type l|grep \/11
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/11/devices/0000:00:14.4
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/11/devices/0000:05:06.0
/sys/kernel/iommu_groups/11/devices/0000:05:05.0
```

So we have to add 05:05 and 05:06 (the two PCI cards of the group) to `qemu`,with `libvirt`. This is easy using virt-manager add hardware, selecting pci host.
Now we boot and..another error appears in `dmesg`:

```
"Flags mismatch irq 21. 00000000 (vfio-intx(0000:05:05.0)) vs. 0000000....usb...."
```

This means our system cannot share interrupts, so we have to remove the device from the host.

So we have to find the interrupts:

```
cat /proc/interrupts | grep 21
```

It return for example usb2, so we search for usb dir:

```
find  /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:* -iname usb2
```

,go to usb dir,in my case 13.2:

```
cd /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:13.2/
```

and remove(sic!) from the host:

```
echo -n 1 > remove
```

Now when starting  the guest,the pci cards are assigned to it.

And for return to us?
I will add answer...if I find the solution!